# Twilio Voice call message restriction to Say once

Tags: c#, twilio

I am using Twilio Rest API (with C#) for sending voice call notifications. Messages are delivering to the users successfully, but messages are repeating multiple times. How do I restrict to say the message only once?

Comment: Can you update your post with the code you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script for [making the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post) which seems as it is working probably looks something like this:

```
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    string AuthToken = "your_auth_token";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var options = new CallOptions();
    options.Url = "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml";
    options.To = "+1XXXXXXXXXX";
    options.From = "+1XXXXXXXXXX";
    var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);

    Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
  }
}
```

And the URL there pointing to some URL of yours containing your TwiML that could look like this [in C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp):

```
    public void Example()
    {
        var response = new TwilioResponse();
        response.Say("This shall only be heard once.");

        Assert.IsTrue(IsValidTwiML(response.ToXDocument()));
    }
```

Also, [note if you have a `loop` parameter specified](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say#nesting-rules) on your `<Say>`:

The `loop` attribute specifies how many times you'd like the text repeated. The default is once. Specifying '0' will cause the  verb to loop until the call is hung up.

Comment: Hi Megan, Thank You for the response. We were using Menu Twimlet (http://twimlets.com/menu) and we don't have control on creation of TwiML document. Now we are working on our own URI for TwiML document as you mentioned. So I think we will be able to solve the issue. Thank You Again for your response, RamiReddy